# Using Nodejs with IIS for REST service using Express

Tags: node.js, rest, express, iis

We're using Nodejs + Express to create a RESTful web service. During testing we kicked off the service via the command-line, i.e., **node mim.js** and and tested the service using http://server:9999/mim/GetEmployeeData and that works fine.

The node application lives in inetpub\wwroot\myapps\mim and we want to be able to access it like so:

http://apps.mydomain.com/mim/GetEmployeeData

We're not quite sure how to get this to work with IIS, however. Looking for some help with respect to this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this Hosting node.js applications in IIS on Windows tutorial:

- https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode

It explains many different scenarios and since you din't post a lot of details it's hard to give you a more detailed answer other than pointing you to a good documentation about the thing that you're trying to do.